# Strange error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Every once in a while I get about 10 - 20 identical errors on my asp.net app.  It's always the same, and I'm wondering if it is someone trying to hack in (it happens about once a month).

> **Source:** System.Web
>
> **Message:** The file '/~/Default.aspx' does not exist.
>
> **User IP:** 89.122.29.80
>
> **User Browser:** Unknown 0.0
>
> **User OS:** Unknown
>
> **Stack trace:**    at
>   System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context,
>   Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   noAssert)  at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType,
>   HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)  at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath)  at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath, String
>   physicalPath)  at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType,
>   VirtualPath path, String
>   pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig) 
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean completedSynchronously)

why on earth would someone be trying to access "/~/Default.aspx" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happens if you are trying to set the NavigateUrl on a HyperLink control too late in the page lifecycle. Make sure that you are not creating HyperLinks in your code behind after the relative Urls are generated.

Comment: Looks like the "NavigateURL" on my RadMenu is being set wrong...I'm going to try and find a way to fix it.  Basically the HTML is correct, so navigating the site to the average user is fine, but the Javascript is messed up, and any bot trying to crawl based on the JS gets sent to the wrong page.

Answer (score 1):

On any well trafficked web site you'll get numerous 404 errors from badly written crawlers, badly written caching servers anti-virus software and browser toolbar add-ons as they each try to second guess what URLs lead off a page.  Often they will misinterpret embedded Javascript trying to figure out what pages it might be linking to.

BUT I've never seen one with a ~ character in it.  That implies you had a ~ on a page which implies that you have a literal ~/Default.aspx occurring somewhere on a page.  Can you find the page in question and do view source on it to see if there's a ~ somewhere on it?

If you vary the page contents according to user agent, can you replay the same request and look at the source?

Have you run a link checker against you site?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of the robot or the crawler.